# how to calculate r-tree's height?

Tags: tree, height, max, css, r-tree

i have a deep doubt about r'tree's height.

if leaf node : N, fanout : m

then r'tree's max height : log m (N) - 1 ?

why this differs from b'tree?

Answer (score 0):

Leaf pages have approximately the double capacity of directory nodes when storing point data: for a rectangle you need to save max and min for each dimension.